# is there any way to work only with changed records in before update MySQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need a statement that allows to change some fields in table1 when table2 was updated.

I have currently the following code:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER check BEFORE UPDATE ON table2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Count <> OLD.Count THEN
        ...
    END IF;
END//
delimiter ;
```

However, table1 is very large and there are a lot of update events, so I'm afraid that this code can slowdown my server. So I want to know if **there is some solution that will not look over all records** in it, but only those updated?

Comment: @user your code does exactly that, the inner block any gets executed for updates where new.count <> old.count. If you worry about slowness, time a big update with and without trigger and see if it slows you down too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trigger will not "look" over all records. Because you declared the trigger as `FOR EACH ROW` only a single row will be dealt with in the trigger.

As the trigger is execute for each row, `NEW` and `OLD` reference a **single** row as, which means that the condition `NEW.Count <> OLD.Count` simply compares two (simple) column values

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name , I've understood the next: the trigger will works for each updated record. so that construction operates not all records in table but all updated records. Is it what You mean?

Comment: @JEXcom: Correct. The trigger is only called for each modified row.